# Integration testing Maven jar in a Jetty container

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-jetty-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I have a Maven project which produces a jar file that is meant to be used in a web service. It has integration tests which use the `jetty-maven-plugin` to run.

In order to run the integration tests on the compiled jar file, I've had to create a dependency with `<systemPath>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</systemPath>`. The integration tests run as I had hoped, using the compiled jar file and correctly creating the web-app out of the `src/test` directory.

So in terms of this projects build, this setup works very well.

The problem is that the POM file, which is deployed during the release process, still has the `systemPath` dependency. This means that projects which *use* the jar are reporting an error during the build. The error says that the jar file "must specify an absolute path". These builds don't fail, but the logs are cluttered and misleading.

I'm looking to remove this `systemPath` from the POM which is deployed to our Maven repository. How can we do this?

For reference, here is the relevant portion of the project's POM.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.7.v20131107</version>
      <configuration>
        <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/webapp</webAppSourceDirectory>
        <classesDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</classesDirectory>
        <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</systemPath>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>start-jetty</id>
          <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
            <daemon>true</daemon>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>stop-jetty</id>
          <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>stop</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jetty's documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-run-goal) regarding `<classesDirectory>` reads:

> Location of your compiled classes for the webapp. [...]

So, this should be `${project.build.testOutputDirectory}` rather than `${project.build.testSourceDirectory}`, shouldn't it?

`<useTestClasspath>` isn't mentioned in [Jetty's doc](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-run-goal).

Is it possible to `install` the dependency and use [`<scope>provided`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies)? Since with that:

> [the dependency] is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The integration test runs as part of the Maven `verify` phase which runs before the `install` phase in the lifecycle. So that would not work for using <scope>provided, right?

Comment: @DavidV That's right, but you could bind the [maven-install-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/) to a prior phase, `pre-integration-test` for instance.

Comment: I changed to using `${project.build.testOutputDirector}` and use `<scope>runtime</scope>`. Then I was able to remove the `systemPath` and everything works well.

Comment: @DavidV Great that you were successful! And thank you for your feedback (after quite a time ;). You could make your final solution an answer on its own. Comments aren't that prominent compared to answers and usually not read first by seekers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a slight modification from [Gerold Broser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489143/650176).

Here are the relevant sections:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.5.v20140505</version>
    <configuration>
        <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/webapp</webAppSourceDirectory>
        <classesDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```